# grunt-jekyllのGulp.js版について、gulp-jekyllの代わりになるものを探しています

Tags: javascript, gulp

GruntからJekyllを操作するのに[grunt-jekyll](https://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll)を使っていますがGulp.jsで同様のプラグインはないでしょうか？dannygarcia氏の[gulp-jekyll](https://github.com/dannygarcia/gulp-jekyll)は2014年1月のfirst commitから更新されておらず代わりになるものがないかと探しています。

grunt-jekyllは複数のconfigファイルを指定できることが特に気に入っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GruntとGulpは両方タスクマネージャーツールですが、考え方は[違います](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1408/19/news035_2.html).

Gruntではconfigファイルにプロジェクトのルールを設定しながら、Gulpではまず、普通のCommonJS的なパッケージのようなrequire等を使うモジュールを作成してタスクを書いたり、あるプラグインもGruntより単純で一つか二つの機能（できるだけ一つ）しか実行しないし、[ワークフロー](https://github.com/osscafe/gulp-cheatsheet)も違います。

簡単に言いますと、ほとんどプラグイン必要はないと思います。

### プラグインなしでやり方

まず[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/)をダウンロードすること。

```
gem install jekyll
```

次は、タスクファイルでインストールされたJekyllのコマンドを起動することです。NodeJSのビルトイン[child_process](http://nodejs.jp/nodejs.org_ja/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)モジュールを使って新しいプロセスを始めることができます。

```
require('child_process').spawn( コマンド名, [argsの整列], [options] )
// それか
require('child_process').exec( )
```

それで、

```
require('child_process').spawn( 'jekyll', ['build'], { stdio: 'inherit' } );
```

以上です。

### Node.JS説明書から

#### `child_process.spawn(command, [args], [options])`

- `command {String}` 実行するコマンド
- `args {Array}` 文字列による引数の配列
- `options {Object}`

  - `stdio`{Array|String}` 子プロセスの標準入出力の設定 (後述)。
  - ...

---

是非わかりにくい点があったら、添削してくださると嬉しいです。